# Developing chat application with PubNub

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I have to create an ability for users to chat with each other. I found that [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) is a great tool to solve this. But it seems to be not so easy as I expected(.

After user login in he is on the screen of **conversations**. Conversations are stored on my server in database. Example of conversation row in db: *conversationID, conversationName, string - user IDs separated by space*. 
To get a list of conversations I can send a request to my server database, get it and display on the screen. Also I have to **subscribe** to all of these conversation channels. The name of the channel for each conversation can be just it's ID number in database I think.

Also, I've created a screen where user can create a conversation. He can select one or multiple companions and send an invite to selected users.

Then when user send invite to another person I have to add new record of conversation in my database and **somehow** notify that user of an invitation. How can I accomplish this? Should I use Push Notifications from PubNub? As described [here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4) I have to register my application to have an ability to get push notifications and then I can send notification to a channel. But how user will get this notification if he is not subscribed to this channel yet? I got stuck here.

Comment: This is more of a design discussion than a question. For that I would recommend contact PubNub to discuss best practices with a Customer Success Manager and Architect. Just send request support@pubnub.com. To answer your last question very quickly - "But how user will get this notification if he is not subscribed to this channel yet?" - Every user will subscribe to their very own "private channel" (based on their username, perhaps). This channel name is well-know or knowable expose by your application (under the covers, not visually). Send an invite on the user's private channel.

Answer (score 8):

First, there are a lot of different approaches regarding chat and how to structure it, how to structure channels, etc. Just for a good reading on alternatives, I recommend using an [inbound channel pattern to descrease history API calls](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/inbound-channel-pattern-decreasing-history-api-calls/). This talks about some interesting ways to reduce channel clutter, but I'll stick with talking through your current design.

In terms of how to approach it given the current design, every user should always subscribe to a unique channel for that user. This way you can use this channel to "signal" to the user (publish a message to their channel) that can facilitate many workflows:

- receive a new conversation invite (so they can reply to it)
- receive a new channel to subscribe to
- remove a conversation (if that's a possibility)
- etc.

### Stream Controller & Channel Groups

You can also use the [Stream Controller add-on](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-controller), to create a [Channel Group](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channel-groups) per user. Channel Groups can also be thought of as Subscribe Groups, because it is a group of channels you are subscribing to (you can't publish to a channel group, only a channel). Using this, on the user-client side, they would always subscribe to their unique Channel Group, in that group would have the unique user channel, plus, all the other conversation channels they would be subscribed to.

In this scenario, user-1 would send an invite to user-2 to join a conversation (server publishes it to user-2's unique channel), user-2 responds back to server, if they accept, the ***server*** then adds the new conversation channel to each of user-1 and user-2's channel groups! On the client side, neither user actually has to change anything, since they are already subscribed to their channel group.

Comment: hai how to add user to my chat in ios

Comment: subscribe to the channel the user needs to chat on.

Comment: how to add multiple users to same channel in ios ? otherwise how to added group chat

Comment: Each user subscribes to the same channel and publishes to that channel.